# 90's dark knight cartoon

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, wizards

Help me identify a 90s gothic cartoon. All I can remember are three main characters. One of them was a dark knight summoned from his grave in order to kill a warrior in every episode. This warrior was helped by a wizard/priest. The whole theme of the animation was really dark. As much as I can remember it was a series.

First of all, I want to thank you for your interest in my question. These memories of this cartoon began when I heard a song where the intro they used seemed familiar to me. I born in 95'at Greece and I remember watching this before I was 5, so it must be a 90s cartoon. I remember it was translated into Greek for sure. The song I am telling you about is this

All I can recall was that it was a medieval gothic cartoon and I can really remember this Dark Knight that didn't talk at all, he just wanted to kill our main protagonist. This Dark Knight was called in every episode in order to kill our protagonist warrior. Our protagonist was always helped by a guy with magic powers and he looked like a medieval priest. That's all. I really appreciate any effort to help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something that might help is the country you lived in while watching this and what language was spoken on the show. Feel free to add the info into the question. Also, stop by our [help] and [tour] for more info about the site.

Comment: So there were a knight, a wizard, and a priest? Or do you mean the warrior as the third character?

Comment: That image is from one of the Batman videos. Batman is sometimes known at the Dark Knight, but he never kills.